# Harmonic functions, equivalence of boundary conditions with phenomena outside domain.

Tags: harmonic-functions, potential-theory

I'm study a article and it contains:

> "It is well known that harmonic functions are associated with boundary
>   conditions, which equivalently means that they depend upon the
>   phenomena occurring outside the given domain."

Can someone give a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A harmonic function satisfies the Laplace equation, and since you consider harmonic functions on a domain, it is a solution to the Dirichelt problem with boundary data a continuous function f. But the boundary is "outside" of your domain, because a domain is an open and connected set.